# Trying to call jQuery plugin function on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery plugin development for a new internship at my university.

I have been messing around trying to build a plugin that gives an element a random background color when clicked.

It works when simply called, i.e.

```
$("#test").click(randomBackground);
```

but when I try to call it with a click, I can't get it to work.

Here is my jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/theluigi/yTy3C/18/

Comment: did you look at the error console and see you were getting `randomize is not defined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$("#test").on('click', function(){$(this).randomize()});
```

Comment: The `on` is not necessary. Simply `$("#test").click(function(){$(this).randomize()});` will do the trick.

Comment: thank you. could you explain why simply
`$("#test").click(randomize);`
doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Another version....

```
  randomize = function () {
            var randomBackground = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
            $(this).css("background-color", randomBackground);
        };

    $("#test").click(randomize);
```